# Enviar datos json en php a un archivo js

Tags: php, javascript, jsonarray

Estoy intentando mandar datos de json que vienen desde php, a un archivo js.

Al utilizar el método de `$ajax`

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        datatype: 'text'
        }).done(function (response) 
        {
            resultado = response;
            console.log(resultado);
        });
```

La respuesta que recibo es array en null y error, en cambio desde el mismo archivo que mando json en array esta lleno.

La primera imagen es array hecho desde php, utlizando json_enconde .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta a función de $ajax
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la salida del var_dump

```
[![introducir el código aquí][3]][3]
```

Por ultimo la salida de console.log
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu petición `AJAX` tienes `type` como `POST`; sin embargo dentro de tu `index.php` usas `$_GET`; el **PHP** (permiteme expresarlo así) esta esperando que tu petición `AJAX` sea algo como:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST', // Desde luego lo correcto seria GET
   url: 'index.php?CodigoVenta=[ValorDelParámetro]',
   datatype: 'text'
}).done(function (response) 
{
  resultado = response;
  console.log(resultado);
});
```

Hecho lo anterior ya solo resta que tu llamada a `ctrMostrarClientes` opere bien con los datos que le pases.

Desde luego otra opción es que uses el [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y en este envíes el parámetro `CodigoVenta` y cambiar en `index.php` tu `$_GET` por el `$_POST`.

Comment: muchas gracias @RobertoLeOr , pero tengo una segunda duda si  los datos del get llegan por url, como tendria hacer funcion para leerlo en javascript

Comment: Saludos. ¿Su duda es como leer/obtener del componente (en el HTML) su valor para pasarlo como `CodigoVenta`  en la **url**?

Comment: Ja le solucionado , muchas gracias RobertoLEor